# Value not equal to textbox entry for discount code

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a simple discount code which is working ok, but I want to display an error message when the incorrect code entered. I've worked this out so far but the message displays all the time rather than only when an incorrect code is entered.

```
    $discount = ( int )$_GET[ 'discount' ];;
    $codes = array(10, 20);

    if ($discount == "10"){
        $discount_total = round($grand_total * ((100-10) / 100), 2);;
        $message = "Discount Code '" . $discount . "' has been successfully applied.";
    }elseif (!in_array(intval($discount), $codes, true)){
        $message = "Sorry, this code is not valid.";
        $discount_total = $grand_total;
    }else {
        $discount_total = $grand_total;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very beginning you already casted your `$discount` variable to `int` type:

```
$discount = ( int )$_GET[ 'discount' ];
```

Just trust your code.

```
$codes = array(10, 20);
// if ($discount == "10") { <--- this is bad, you compare your int value with string "10"
if ($discount === 10) { // <-- this is clear code
    $discount_total = round($grand_total * ((100-10) / 100), 2);;
    $message = "Discount Code '" . $discount . "' has been successfully applied.";
// } elseif (!in_array(intval($discount), $codes, true)){ <-- same mistake here, we dont need to cast $discount again
} elseif (!in_array($discount, $codes)) { // <-- this should just work fine, the only question: if you already checked value 10, why not just to check 20? why do you check against array of 2 values?
    $message = "Sorry, this code is not valid.";
    $discount_total = $grand_total;
} else {
    $discount_total = $grand_total;
}
```

**Update** If you want to check if GET parameter was sent you can wrap  all this fragment with:

```
if (isset($_GET['discount'])) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, the issue seems to lie with the second statement. Is it correct? If the value entered in the discount textbox is not equal either code in the array, then the message should display. It seems to work but the message displays as soon as the page is loaded, before any value is entered, which is what I don't want.